# Constrain Rust method to accept two variables of a valid type pair

Tags: rust

I have a struct that has some common fields, but there are two fields that must contain related types. I also want to implement a `new` method that would allow combining only valid pairs. This would greatly improve struct ergonomics.

To illustrate that. I've got a struct named `Query`, which has the following fields:

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Query<V, U> {
    pub value: V,
    pub unit: U,
    pub name: String,
}
```

`value` can be either of `Time` or `Distance` type, `unit` can be either of `TimeUnit` or `DistanceUnit` type.

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Time;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum TimeUnit {
    Seconds,
    Hours,
    Days,
    Weeks,
    Months,
    Years,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Distance;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum DistanceUnit {
    Meters,
    Kilometers,
    Miles,
}
```

Having such kind of structure makes it easy to implement `new` generic methods:

```rs
impl Query<Time, TimeUnit> {
    pub fn new(value: Time, unit: TimeUnit, name: String) -> Self {
        Self { value, unit, name }
    }
}

impl Query<Distance, DistanceUnit> {
    pub fn new(value: Distance, unit: DistanceUnit, name: String) -> Self {
        Self { value, unit, name }
    }
}
```

However this leaves a hole and allows creating such kind of struct manually:

```rs
/// Do not allow creating query with Time and DistanceUnit and vice-versa
fn do_not_allow_such_case() {
    let _ = Query {
        value: Time {},
        unit: DistanceUnit::Kilometers,
        name: "query".into(),
    };
}
```

The alternative and probably a better approach would be making impossible states impossible to represent, so I'd refactor struct by introducing an Enum with allowed pairs:

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Pair {
    Time(Time, TimeUnit),
    Distance(Distance, DistanceUnit),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Query2 {
    pub query: Pair,
    pub name: String,
}
```

I like this way better, however I struggle to implement a `new` method as in previous case. My first thought was to implement `From` traits for previously declared enums and implement a generic `new` method where I could use these `From` traits as constraints:

```rs
impl From<(Time, TimeUnit)> for Pair {
    fn from(q: (Time, TimeUnit)) -> Self {
        Self::Time(q.0, q.1)
    }
}

impl From<(Distance, DistanceUnit)> for Pair {
    fn from(q: (Distance, DistanceUnit)) -> Self {
        Self::Distance(q.0, q.1)
    }
}
```

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ValueEnum {
    Time(Time),
    Distance(Distance),
}

impl From<Time> for ValueEnum {
    fn from(v: Time) -> Self {
        Self::Time(v)
    }
}

impl From<Distance> for ValueEnum {
    fn from(v: Distance) -> Self {
        Self::Distance(v)
    }
}
```

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum UnitEnum {
    Time(TimeUnit),
    Distance(DistanceUnit),
}

impl From<TimeUnit> for UnitEnum {
    fn from(u: TimeUnit) -> Self {
        Self::Time(u)
    }
}

impl From<DistanceUnit> for UnitEnum {
    fn from(u: DistanceUnit) -> Self {
        Self::Distance(u)
    }
}
```

And this is my attempt to implement `new` method, but it would not compile.

```rs
impl Query2 {
    pub fn new<V, U>(value: V, unit: U, name: String) -> Self
    where
        V: Into<ValueEnum>,
        U: Into<UnitEnum>,
        /// No idea how to constrain the pair
    {
        Self {
            /// This would not allow compiling
            query: (value, unit).into(),
            name,
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

This is a link to Rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=64ac6f5cb9b439e9943925c7ee8dd2e6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use traits and associated types

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;
pub trait Value {
    type Unit: Debug;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Time;

impl Value for Time {
    type Unit = TimeUnit;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum TimeUnit {
    Seconds,
    Hours,
    Days,
    Weeks,
    Months,
    Years,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Query<T: Value> {
    pub value: T,
    pub unit: <T as Value>::Unit,
    pub name: String,
}

impl<T: Value> Query<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T, unit: <T as Value>::Unit, name: String) -> Self {
        Self { value, unit, name }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let time_query: Query<Time> = Query::new(Time {}, TimeUnit::Seconds, "Seconds".to_owned());
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1d188f4ad829719e4f123304bcdc7690)

Another, somewhat simpler way to couple value and it's unit is to make unit a member of value.
This approach has advantage of making API somewhat smaller, but the trade-off is that type of unit becomes essentially unnameable.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Distance {
    unit: DistanceUnit,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum DistanceUnit {
    Meters,
    Kilometers,
    Miles,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Query<T> {
    pub value: T,
    pub name: String,
}

impl Query<Distance> {
    pub fn new(value: Distance, name: String) -> Self {
        Self { value, name }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let time_query: Query<Distance> = Query::<Distance>::new(
        Distance {
            unit: DistanceUnit::Meters,
        },
        "Seconds".to_owned(),
    );
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=76d05453bcb0bdbc1becbcfe9157e62e)

Comment: That's great! I haven't yet used associated types and I'll definitely need to look at them up more. Thank you very much!